# Similar functions behaving differently in my google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I recently made myself a stitch counter in Excel to keep track of my stitches while knitting and decided to try and translate the VBA into Google Sheets. After two weeks of struggling I finally have almost everything that works in Excel working in Google sheets...except for one thing.

I have four buttons to which four separate but similar codes are assigned. Each of these 4 functions change the stitch counter, the only difference is how many stitches are being added.

1. add 1 Stitch
2. add 2 Stitches
3. add 10 Stitches
4. add stitches based on User number

All of these buttons function properly unless every field is blank when the button is pushed. This is where the issue lies: depending on the button pushed (while all fields are blank), a row will also be added (which is not the desired result).

What should be happening: When all fields are blank, adding stitches will trigger a prompt for the user to set their Stitches Per Row, then add stitches depending on the button used. (This does happen if "add 1 Stitch" or "add Stitches based on User Number" is used)

What is actually happening: When all fields are blank, if "add 2 stitches" or "add 10 stitches" is pressed the user is prompted to set their Stitches Per Row, and then is immediately prompted to set their Rows to Completion (which is triggered once the first row is reached), their Row Count is set to 1, and the correct number of stitches is added.

What I cannot for the life of me figure out is why half of the functions behave one way and half behave another.

So below is the code I have written so far. Hopefully someone will be able to see the difference between the two functions that work and the two functions that don't, because it has been alluding me.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // sheets are counted starting from 0
var stitchCount = sheet.getRange("D2:D3");
var changeStitch = stitchCount.getValue();
var rowCount = sheet.getRange("B2:B3");
var changeRow = rowCount.getValue();
var stitchPerRow = sheet.getRange("D5");
var valueSPR = stitchPerRow.getValue();
var rowComplete = sheet.getRange("D6");
var valueRowC = rowComplete.getValue();
var stitchZero = changeStitch - valueSPR;
var userIncrement = sheet.getRange("F12:G12");
var valueUserNum = userIncrement.getValue();
var rowsToAddIfSmallSPR = Math.round(10/valueSPR);
var stitchRolloverIfSmallSPR = (10 % valueSPR);

function resetAll() {
  stitchCount.clearContent();
  rowCount.clearContent();
  stitchPerRow.clearContent();
  rowComplete.clearContent();
  userIncrement.clearContent();
}
function zeroStitch() { 
    stitchCount.setValue("0")
}
function zeroRow() { 
    rowCount.setValue("0")
}
function add1Stitch() { //one stitch
  checkForSPR(); //get user input if SPR isn't set
  if ((changeStitch + 1) === valueSPR) { //if stitchCount completes a row with the additonal stitch
    zeroStitch(); //zero out Stitches
    add1Row(); // add a row
  } else if (changeStitch > valueSPR){ //if stitchCount completes a row with leftovers
      stitchCount.setValue(changeStitch - valueSPR); //figure out leftovers-->stitchCount
      add1Row(); // add a row
  } else {
  stitchCount.setValue(changeStitch+1); //if row not complete with additional stitch simply add 1 stitch
  }
}
function add2Stitches() { //two stitches
  checkForSPR(); //get user input if SPR isn't set

  if ((changeStitch + 2) === valueSPR) { //if stitchCount completes row w/ additional 2 stitches
    zeroStitch(); //zero out stitches
    add1Row(); //add a row
  } else if ((changeStitch +2) > valueSPR) { //if stitchCount completes row w/ leftovers
      stitchCount.setValue((changeStitch +2) - valueSPR); //figure out leftovers-->stitchCount
      add1Row(); // add a row
  } else {
  stitchCount.setValue(changeStitch+2); //if row not complete with additional stitches simply add 2 stitches
  }
}
function add10Stitches() {
    checkForSPR();
    if ((changeStitch +10) > valueSPR) {
        stitchCount.setValue((changeStitch +10) - valueSPR);
    checkSPRLessThan10();
  } else if ((changeStitch + 10) === valueSPR) {
    zeroStitch();
    checkSPRLessThan10();
  } else {
  stitchCount.setValue(changeStitch+10);
  }
}
function checkSPRLessThan10() {
  if(valueSPR < 10) {
    stitchCount.setValue(changeStitch + stitchRolloverIfSmallSPR);
    rowCount.setValue(changeRow + rowsToAddIfSmallSPR);
  } else {
    add1Row();
  }
}
function addStitchUserNum() {
  checkForSPR();
  if ((changeStitch + valueUserNum) === valueSPR) {
    zeroStitch();
    add1Row();
  } else if (changeStitch > valueSPR){
      stitchCount.setValue(changeStitch - valueSPR);
      add1Row();
  } else {
  stitchCount.setValue(changeStitch+valueUserNum);
  }
}
function addRowUserNum() {
  rowCount.setValue(changeRow+valueUserNum)
}
function add1Row() {
  rowCount.setValue(changeRow+1);
  checkForRC();
}
function sub1Stitch() {
  stitchCount.setValue(changeStitch-1)
}
function sub1Row() {
  rowCount.setValue(changeRow-1);
}
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show prompt', 'showPrompt')
      .addToUi();
}
function inputStitchPerRow() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Stitches per Row',
      'Please enter the number of stitches needed to complete a row',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    stitchPerRow.setValue(text);
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('You didn\'t set your stitches per row, please set manually');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Please set stitches per row manually');
  }
}
function checkForSPR() {
  if (valueSPR == "") {
    inputStitchPerRow();
  }
}
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show prompt', 'showPrompt')
      .addToUi();
}
function inputRowComplete() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response = ui.prompt(
   'Rows to Complete Project',
   'Please enter the number of rows needed to complete your project', 
   ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
 // Process the user's response.
 if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
   rowComplete.setValue(response.getResponseText());
 } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
   ui.alert('Please set your Rows to Completion');
 } else {
   ui.alert('Please set your Rows to Completion');
 }
}
function checkForRC() {
  if(valueRowC == "") {
      inputRowComplete();
    }
  }
```

Please let me know if I can be more clear, or if I'm asking this in the wrong place. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you consolidate your code to:

```
function add1Stitch() {
  addStitches(1);
}

function add2Stitches() { //two stitches
  addStitches(2);
}

function add10Stitches() {
  addStitches(10);
}

function addStitches(numberOfStichesToAdd) {
  checkForSPR(); //get user input if SPR isn't set
  Logger.log('changeStitch: ' + changeStitch)
  Logger.log('valueSPR: ' + valueSPR)

  if ((changeStitch + numberOfStichesToAdd) === valueSPR) { //if stitchCount completes a row with the additonal stitch
    zeroStitch(); //zero out Stitches
    add1Row(); // add a row
    if (numberOfStichesToAdd === 10) {
      checkSPRLessThan10();
    }
  } else if ((changeStitch + numberOfStichesToAdd) > valueSPR){ //if stitchCount completes a row with leftovers
    stitchCount.setValue((changeStitch + numberOfStichesToAdd) - valueSPR); //figure out leftovers-->stitchCount
    add1Row(); // add a row
  } else {
    stitchCount.setValue(changeStitch + numberOfStichesToAdd); //if row not complete with additional stitch simply add 1 stitch
  }
}
```

Run the code, and then use the "View" menu to view the "Logs"  In any case, you need to do some debugging by printing values to the Log with `Logger.log()`

We don't know what values are in the spreadsheet and being retrieved.  If you can provide what the values of critical variables are, that would help.